# Alternative to Tuples

Tags: asp.net

As .net framework 4.0 supports Tuples. Tuple Class is not available in 3.5 But Is there any way i can create my own class MyTuple in .net 3.5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can create your own tuples. There isn't anything hard about it. Here's an example with a `Tuple<T1, T2>` and `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>`.

```
public class Tuple<T1, T2>
{
    public Tuple(T1 item1, T2 item2)
    {
        this.Item1 = item1;
        this.Item2 = item2;
    }

    public T1 Item1 { get; private set; }

    public T2 Item2 { get; private set; }
}

public class Tuple<T1, T2, T3>
{
    public Tuple(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3)
    {
        this.Item1 = item1;
        this.Item2 = item2;
       this.Item3 = item3;
    }

    public T1 Item1 { get; private set; }

    public T2 Item2 { get; private set; }

    public T3 Item3 { get; private set; }
}
```

And here is the static factory class for creating `Tuple` instances:

```
public static class Tuple
{
    public static Tuple<T1, T2> Create<T1, T2>(
        T1 item1, T2 item2)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2>(item1, item2);
    }

    public static Tuple<T1, T2, T3> Create<T1, T2, T3>(
        T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3>(item1, item2, item3);
    }
}
```

Now you can write the following:

```
var myTuple = Tuple.Create(4, "oh yes baby");
```

Cheers

Comment: Don't forget to override Equals and GetHashCode to handle equality checks.