# C# alternative to tuple

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have a dbf file (dBase) that I want to read, put each row into a single list (since a row represents data about one shapefile object), and then be able to modify the list (e.g., convert fields which represent the name to a string). This means that the datatype need to be able to hold both Ints, strings, bool and so on, and add items to, it. In python I could do this with lists, but since sets cant be modified, I cant use them.

This sounds like a (exact) duplicate to [Alternative to Tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067761/alternative-to-tuples),
but it isn't. These questions are based on the assumption that you know which objects you want beforehand; I don't.

I'm on .NET 4.5, btw.

Comment: Can you provide some example code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) - it is a perfect use case for it:

> Visual C# 2010 introduces a new type, dynamic. The type is a static type, but an object of type dynamic bypasses static type checking. In most cases, it functions like it has type object. At compile time, an element that is typed as dynamic is assumed to support any operation. Therefore, you do not have to be concerned about whether the object gets its value from a COM API, from a dynamic language such as IronPython, from the HTML Document Object Model (DOM), from reflection, or from somewhere else in the program. However, if the code is not valid, errors are caught at run time.

Comment: Not to be too picky, but that is a feature of C# 4.0, not Visual C# 2010; Visual C# 2010 is a product whereas C# 4.0 is a language. You can use C# 4.0 on both VS 2010 and VS 2012. Just wanted to make sure that was clear. :-)

Comment: @Karl - You shall have to be picky with MSDN, which is where the quote is from ;)

Comment: @Oded - LOL, I was just bustin' your chops. ;)

Comment: @jpaugh - LOL, you don't get to say that very often, huh?

Comment: Not to be pickier, but it's not just a feature of the C# 4.0 language, but also the .NET 4.0 runtime.

Comment: @Karl Perhaps too often. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to easily add properties at runtime and change their types, you can use [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) with `dynamic`, for example:

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();

expando.SomeProperty = "1234";

Console.WriteLine(expando.SomeProperty);
Console.WriteLine(expando.SomeProperty.GetType().FullName); // string

expando.SomeProperty = int.Parse(expando.SomeProperty);

Console.WriteLine(expando.SomeProperty);
Console.WriteLine(expando.SomeProperty.GetType().FullName); // int
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `dynamic` type?